# 1 year survival plan for nuclear war

Tags: lifespan

Let's say less than 20 [W91](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/W91)-comparable bombs explode major government and civilian targets, but that the fallout covers ~50% of population including my area (in the rural part of the country). My immediate plan would be to get inside, shut down the AC, seal any cracks, fill containers with water before the utility lines get contaminated, and start living off the pantry. However this can only get me 1 month in (actually only a few days because of the limited air). What are my options if I want to make it 1 year?

Comment: Have you looked at any of the hundreds of books about this subject?

Comment: You wouldn't last a week.

Comment: Buy a disused government fallout shelter, refurbish and re-stock it. Then live there 24/7 waiting for the event to happen.

Comment: To be the honest, it would be better to rephrase your question to one month as most variables for a one year survival would be unknown.

Comment: If you live in a "rural part of the country" it's likely your water is from a well and might well remain uncontaminated -- but will be inaccessible once the power goes out, barring a hand- or wind-powered pump.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite obvious that you do not understand even the beginning of the project you try to "plan". I will not copy / paste here everything that was written on the subject, for several obvious reasons.

**Short answer**

If your plan starts AFTER the event, then you do not even need to bother. Just live happy till the end of life, do not think about anything that has the potential to upset you.

**Longer answer**

To understand the size of the project, do the following experiment for 1 year (the time you consider for staying "inside"):

- make a detailed list of everything that you buy; for each item clearly write down the size and the number of kilograms; additionally, write anything else that looks important to you; at the end of the year add all volumes, and all kilograms, and all the money spent; that will help you with calculating the size of the shelter;
- collect everything that you "do" when you go to the restroom, and all the water you use to clean it; also all the paper and other things that you use there;
- collect all the garbage, instead of dumping it.

Now multiply things with the number of people who have to live there. Add a few extra not-yet-born people to the list; one year is long and boring, and you might get ideas ;) And please take into consideration that the new people will be unbelievable garbage and poop generators.

Take into consideration that things will get broken and they will need to be repaired.

You will need light. Electricity might not be readily available, fuel might be scarce (for running electricity generators), open fire uses oxygen.

Refrigerators and freezers also need electricity - if you still have it.

---

Everything I wrote above came from the top of my head. I did not even open a search engine.

---

People almost "have gone mad" by staying inside during COVID. With all utilities available, with electricity, food. Also going out for shopping. After the event you mention, you will suddenly be in a totally different world. In reality, nobody really has that kind of experience, to know how things would evolve.

---

If things would be so easy, people would already travel to Mars. The trip there only takes about 8 months (if I remember correctly) instead of your hypothetical 1 year.

Answer (score 0):

**One year survival plan for nuclear war?**

First of all, one needs to educate oneself on how exactly to deal with this situation. There are many variables that we may not foresee. Will we even be in a building when or if a nuclear warhead explodes in our vicinity!

The first 24 hours are the most critical. Then the next 7 days are very critical. This is followed by the next 30 days. Then there is the long duration of time! [FEMA](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=4f44CZLVJaU) recommends one (1) gallon of water per day per person in an emergency!

First of all, we must educate ourselves!

Here is a YouTube video that certainly contains very practical insights about this topic: [Individual Protection Against Atomic Attack (US Army Training Film, 1957)](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=AEmB1pNQMHg)

Shutting down the AC and all exterior outside air ducks, sealing any cracks, fill containers with water before the utility lines get contaminated, and start living off the pantry is just the beginning of things to do. A year is a long time to prepare for.

- Start prepping with long term term food stuffs, like **water**, rice, beans, oats, powdered milk, etc.
- Start with enough **water** to get you through a week at least. A month would be great. If water sources are out of commission, have some form of purification system for your water that you gathered from outside. A year supply of water is huge! [FEMA](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=4f44CZLVJaU) recommends one (1) gallon of water per day per person in cases of emergencies.
- Make as much [hardtack](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardtack) as you are comfortably storing. Ordinary bread will go mouldy rather soon, but hardtack lasts for years and years if cooked right! Ovens may not be functioning in this scenario.
- If one is on permanent medication, make sure to have a long supply. I take my own medicine on long hacking trips along with a pill cutter, just in case I have to make due with less in the case of an emergency.
- If possible, get a solar generator for running a refrigerator
- Make a solar cooker for cooking. Electrical and gases may be non-existent.
- Candles will give off light and generate a little heat. (Stay in a small, yet most protected room in the building, one with no external wall to the outside.  If there is external radiation in the atmosphere, the further away from that danger is best. Radiation will eventually contaminate the exterior walls of your dwelling. Rooms away from the dominant winds would be betters than those facing these winds. Basements are best because of the earth being a great buffer to protect you.) Beeswax candles, although more expensive will generally last three times longer than other types of candles.
- [Protect electronics against an EMP (Electromagnetic Pulse)](https://uwkcase.com/blogs/blog/how-to-protect-electronics-against-an-emp-electromagnetic-pulse)
- Lead is great against radiation, but few have access to it. Earth is also a great source of protection if deep enough; at least two metres thick.
- Have books on hand to read that may help you pass the time, cards or board games can give one distraction too

Comment: "most protected room in the building, one with no external wall to the outside" - shouldn't the entire building be underground for that purpose? It is unlikely that many people would survive, taking shelter in a sky-scrapper.

Comment: @virolino If there is external radiation in the atmosphere, the further away from that danger is best. Radiation will eventually contaminate the exterior walls of your dwelling. Basements are best.because of the earth being a great buffer to protect you.

Comment: A year's supply of water -- assuming you'll want/need to wash, and for adequate drinking supply, that's roundly 600 gallons (~2300 liters) per person...

Comment: @KenGraham: as far as I know, the only rooms in buildings above ground WITHOUT exterior walls are restrooms (WC), storage rooms, some elevator shafts, some staircases (and possibly a few others). They are OK for temporary shelter (a few hours to a few days), but they become highly unsuitable for long time, I guesstimate. And that is... only if the building stands.